# Regex use in Notepad++, searching

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a bunch of JSON key-value pairs. Most of them are empty, like this

```
"object": []
```

However, some of them aren't. I want to use Notepad++'s regex search to find every "object" that has something between the []. I know this is a very basic question, but I don't know anything about regexes except that they could probably be used to solve this problem. If someone can take a few seconds to answer my question it'd save me a lot of searching. Thanks!

Comment: search for: `\[.+\]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just search for

```
\[.+\]
```

[image]

Comment: What if I have something like "object": [

Comment: "contents", "contents2"

Comment: I mean, the contents are on the next line

Comment: @Adam can you put a better sample data and your expected matches?

Comment: This might lead to false positives, if there can be more than one such construct in a line.

Comment: `\[\r` seems to be a pretty good approximation. I don't need it to be perfect. Thanks guys

Comment: @Adam if your array values are in the next line, then you might use this search `[\r` using the `Extended` search mode. Btw, did the answer solve your question?